# Where to store TDE password, not at server

Tags: postgresql, tde

I have a linux server with a modified `PostgreSQL` DB which encrypt files at rest, using this [guide](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/products/postgresql-transparent-data-encryption/).

I have installed this modified `PostgreSQL` on server which its DB files are encrypted at rest. and need the password to decrypt them when `db process starts`.

Whenever the server starts/restart, specifically when DB process starts, The DB executes a file which needs to print out the password, lets say `give_pass.sh` with password *1234*

`cat give_pass.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/sh 
echo 1234
```

But I don't want password to be present at server so something like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh 
secured_function_that_gives_password
```

I want to protect the DB files from being exposed in case of a physical theft, so:

1. Make sure if physical db server is stolen, the password won't be present at server, nor it would be reached from executing `give_pass.sh` file, obviously to prevent db files from being accessed.
2. Somehow automate the procedure, meaning if the `db` process fails, it would be restarted, executing `give_pass.sh`, and having the password delivered.

Any ideas how I should go about it?- thanks

Comment: not storing the password on the machine won't prevent physical theft. if they have physical access to the machine, its not yours anymore

Comment: Edited to clarify that I want to prevent files exposed after physical theft, not the theft itself

Comment: right but the password for postgres does not encrypt the data. you can copy the datafiles to another box and tell it to use any password you'd like

Comment: The DB files are encrypted at rest. and need the password to decrypt them when `db process starts`

Comment: You seem to have a security need which exceeds "free help on the internet" territory.  You could have give_pass.sh consult some other on-premises server which is in a locked cupboard in a locked cage in a locked room in a locked building and which is bolted to the floor.  There are professionals who do this kind of thing, which is not a programming task.